# WpDataTable - On Save showing me 403 Permission Denied You do not have permission for this request /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Tags: wordpress

I created a table using 'Create a table by importing data from data source' option but when I tried change value of  'Default rows per page' then it showing me  '403 Permission Denied

You do not have permission for this request /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'

error .  but its working fine when I tried to create table using 'Create a table linked to an existing data source .' option.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Q3X.png)